# How did Magnussen know about Redbeard?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In *Sherlock*,  Magnussen whispers to Sherlock *Redbeard*. So how could he know about Redbeard? Sherlock couldn't tell him because he isn't so stupid. Mycroft won't obviously tell him. So how did Magnussen know about a story so old and so small about 'Redbeard'?

Comment: [Found this](https://www.quora.com/In-Sherlock-TV-show-how-did-Magnussen-know-about-Redbeard) and [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/2ep6ky/request_bbc_sherlock_how_the_hell_could_magnussen/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no logical explanation that we are aware of. It's likely just a plot seed inserted by the creators of the series (out of universe).

### In Universe

Sherlock himself isn't really aware, at this point, of the significance of Redbeard (he still thinks it's a dog).

It seems unlikely that Magnussen is aware of Eurus at this point either as her name does not appear under the list of pressure points applicable to Sherlock.

What *DOES* appear is the name **Jim Moriarty** who we *know* HAS been in contact with Eurus so it's conceivable that Magnussen somehow obtained information (but not all) from him.

> PRESSURE POINT:
>
> IRENE ADLER (SEE FILE)
>
> **JIM MORIARTY (SEE FILE)**
>
> REDBEARD (SEE FILE)
>
> HOUNDS OF THE BASKERVILLE
>
> OPIUM
>
> JOHN WATSON

Comment: So the mind palace is equivalent to cookies in the browser?